# Using JQuery AJAX to grab some data from the Database and print them out according to each DIV ID

Tags: jquery

I was trying to grab some data from the database using JQuery AJAx, and print the data to the DIV with a unique ID.

I got two DIV tags like this:

```
<div id="1" class="myClass">
The content for texting1 is : $printing result from the Test Table which id=1
</div>

<div id="2" class="myClass">
The content for texting2 is : $printing result from the Test Table which id=2
</div>
```

Here is the function in a Controller:

```
  function findcontent($id=null){  
            $this->autoRender=false; 
              $result=$this->Test->findByid($id);               
               if($result){
                return $result['content'];
                            }
               else{
                 return "nothing";


  }
    }  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var id=$("div #myClass").val(); // I am stuck over this line of code
var curl="http://localhost:8080/test/findcontent"+id;

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: curl,   
      success: function(data) { 
      var w=data.substring(0,1);
          alert(data);
                           });
      });
});
</script>
```

I have no idea how to move on since I there are more than two DIV tags in my case.
I need your help.

Comment: A few things, first IDs can't start with a number in HTML4, second would be you need to loop over *each* class (though this is a bad idea, that's *many* AJAX calls), third you can select by class to get the `<div>` elements like this: `$("div.myClass")` (then you need to loop through).  After that I'm not sure what you're after, if it's the ID then it's `.attr('id')` or `[0].id` or `.get(0).id` instead of `.val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: curl,   
      success: function(data) { 
   $("#1").html(data);
             $("#2").html(data);
                           });
      });
});
```

Do you want to add same data in both div?